# Get target of Windows .lnk shortcut using "Start in" directory

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, shortcut, wsh, lnk

I am trying to retrieve the target path of a Windows .lnk shortcut, but the "Target" is not an actual file path according to the .lnk file's properties:

[image]

I am using the IWshRuntimeLibrary and the shortcut object I am accessing is of type IWshShortcut:

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
IWshShortcut link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(lnkFileName);
// This returns "C:\Windows\Installer\{F843C6A3-224D-4615-94F8-3C461BD9AEA0}\PaintShopProExeIcon.ico"
var targetPath = link.TargetPath;
// This is the same as the "Start in" value in the image above
var workingDir = link.WorkingDirectory;
```

The TargetPath property of the "link" object is not the location of the actual .exe: "C:\Windows\Installer{F843C6A3-224D-4615-94F8-3C461BD9AEA0}\PaintShopProExeIcon.ico"

I can get the WorkingDirectory property from this object, which seems to be the same as the "Start in" property of the shortcut as in the image above. My question is, **how can I get the actual target path of the .exe file the shortcut would open, if TargetPath is not the actual .exe path**? Where is this information?

The actual target path in this example is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jasc Software Inc\Paint Shop Pro 9\Paint Shop Pro 9.exe". How does the system know to open "Paint Shop Pro.exe" specifically?

Comment: Looks like a crappy trick called advertised shortcuts.  Tends to be used to "self-heal" an install, a program like this will try to steal file associations back.  Or create desktop icons to programs that are not installed yet.  Best Google query is "msi advertised shortcut".

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution at http://www.geektieguy.com/2007/11/19/how-to-parse-special-lnk-files-aka-msi-shortcuts-aka-windows-installer-advertised-shortcuts-using-c/, which detects the actual target's path of an advertised shortcut.